# URL rewrite is not working in version Apache Tomcat 9.0.30. Why?

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat9

When I make `RewriteEngine` on in `rewrite.config`, tomcat is terminating automatically on startup.

Why is it happening ?

The `rewrite.config` is given below :

```
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]  
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d  
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I am configuring tomcat for url rewriting . I have added below statement in conf/context.xml

```
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
  <JarScanner scanClassPath="false" />
```

and I have kept rewrite.config in apache-tomcat-9.0.30\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF
folder

what else configuration need to be done.

with above configuration i am getting below exception on  start up of tomcat

```
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
            at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [RewriteValve[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
            ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rewriteValve.invalidLine
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse(RewriteValve.java:642)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse(RewriteValve.java:221)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.startInternal(RewriteValve.java:173)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            ... 42 more
```

Comment: Can you add the rewrite.config file? It will be helpful.

Comment: A _httpd_ configuration that causes Tomcat to not start at all? You'll need to give more information than "something doesn't work" - as it stands here, the question is unanswerable because Tomcat doesn't have any information about httpd's configuration, thus this config can't be the cause for a _startup_ to fail

Comment: @OlafKock  its starting with above configuration as explained in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best bet is: You're placing an Apache httpd rewrite configuration into a location where Tomcat expects its own format. If you check [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html), you won't find any `RewriteEngine` directive documented anywhere, and your error message mentions `invalid.line`. Here's your hint.

On top, tagging the question with [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) is quite misleading. Pay attention to your tags (e.g. read the tag's documentation by hovering the mouse)

Comment: I've edited to question to exclude the misleading tag

Comment: thanks. RewriteEngine was wrong configuration. Its working now .